# Attaching PDF file to email sent with AWS SES

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to send an email using AWS SDK from nodejs server and attach a pdf file.
Thought about uploading the file to S3 and sending a link via the email, but then I can't make the bucket public so this option is out. Now I have all the data on the EC2 instance, how do I attach a downloadable PDF to the raw (templated, but not have to be) email I want to send using SES?

Searched for everything in AWS documentation and found nothing. I don't think it is that rare so any insight would be helpful.

P.S. I don't want to use third party module, because I don't want to provide my credentials to unknown module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your requirement is no third party libraries, you will have to write your own. This is not too difficult but it is not easy either.

My suggestion that might meet your requirement is to pick a library that just creates the email message and returns a string to you. Then your private code can manage credentials and the calls to SES. I am not aware of such a library, but you could pick an open source node.js package and extract the code that you need. Then republish just that part so that others can benefit as you did giving credit to the original authors.

For Amazon SES you will need to use the SendRawEmail action. Then you will have to handcraft the body of the message.

Here is an example of how to format the email message:

```
From: "Sender Name" <sender@example.com>
To: recipient@example.com
Subject: Customer service contact info
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a"

--a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="sub_a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a"

--sub_a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Please see the attached file for a list of customers to contact.

--sub_a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Hello!</h1>
<p>Please see the attached file for a list of customers to contact.</p>
</body>
</html>

--sub_a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a--

--a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a
Content-Type: text/plain; name="customers.txt"
Content-Description: customers.txt
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="customers.txt";
    creation-date="Sat, 05 Aug 2017 19:35:36 GMT";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

SUQsRmlyc3ROYW1lLExhc3ROYW1lLENvdW50cnkKMzQ4LEpvaG4sU3RpbGVzLENhbmFkYQo5MjM4
OSxKaWUsTGl1LENoaW5hCjczNCxTaGlybGV5LFJvZHJpZ3VleixVbml0ZWQgU3RhdGVzCjI4OTMs
QW5heWEsSXllbmdhcixJbmRpYQ==

--a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a--
```

This link will explain further:

[Sending Raw Email](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-raw.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I actually used this example and this API method when I created a .txt attachment and as I wrote, it works great. The idea of looking how the third party module wraps a <b>PDF</b> file is a good idea. Also, the official docs has an example in Python, Ruby and Java about how to attach a file with a path to it instead of building it. Didn't find anything in javascript so looked for it here....